# Import an excel sheet data to a table in SQL 2000 from a SP

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

As the self explanatory question depicts that I've got a situation where:-

1. As soon as a user executes a SP, he should get a selection window to choose any desired excel sheet from his machine.
2. After this selection, entire excel sheet data should be imported into a table.

Requirement is pretty straight forward. But the road block is the older version of SQL i.e. 2000.

Any suggestion ?

In response to @MAT:- One of the many things I tried to do is using OPENROWSET:-

```
SELECT *
INTO demoTable
FROM
OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'
,'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Work\Reports\CustomerRecords.xls'
,'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'
)
```

This threw error:-

> Ad hoc access to OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' has been
>   denied. You must access this provider through a linked server.

As I understood, it is an access related issue. So to trouleshoot this I did this:-

> Open regedit.exe and navigate to
>   \Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\Providers\Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 and Create a DWORD named
>   DisallowAdhocAccess with the value 0.

But that also didn't work as while creating a new DWORD, it threw error:-

> ERROR CREATING VALUE - Cannot create value: Error writing to registry.

Comment: Exactly what is your road block?  What have you tried?  What doesn't work?  Why didn't it work?

Comment: @MAT:-  By default, there is no Import and Export Wizard (Data Transformation Services - DTS in SQL Server 2000)

Comment: Are you saying that you've tried nothing at all?  You haven't even tried inserting one row at a time to establish if this would be suitable?

Comment: I tried OPENROWSET as well, it threw error in TSQL.

Comment: Then show your code, and show your error.  You need to demonstrate everything you tried with full details of why it didn't work.  You also haven't explained whether you've attempted inserting one row at a time, and/or why it was unsatisfactory for you.

Comment: @MAT - please check, I've updated the question as you mentioned.